Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL ws://127.0.0.1:42545/eCMb9Es1JfQ=/ws

We have mobile app build using** Flutter**. We got the debug.apk from the dev team.
We need to use appium webdriverIO using typescript for mobile automation with appium flutter finder
Using macOS & VS code

VS code - Terminal logs
Error: 
[0-1] }
[0-1] 2024-09-09T18:26:16.411Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL ws://127.0.0.1:42545/eCMb9Es1JfQ=/ws. Check the server log for more details
[0-1] 2024-09-09T18:26:16.413Z ERROR webdriver: unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL ws://127.0.0.1:42545/eCMb9Es1JfQ=/ws. Check the server log for more details


[c070e00a][FlutterDriver@feb0] Deleting Flutter Driver session
[c070e00a][FlutterDriver@feb0] Cleanup the port forward
[c070e00a][AppiumDriver@7bb2] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1725906376391 (23:56:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[c070e00a][AppiumDriver@7bb2] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot connect to the Dart Observatory URL ws://127.0.0.1:42545/eCMb9Es1JfQ=/ws. Check the server log for more details
    at FlutterDriver.connectSocket (/Users/prabhakary/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/lib/sessions/observatory.ts:125:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at FlutterDriver.connectAndroidSession (/Users/prabhakary/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/lib/sessions/android.ts:49:10)
    at FlutterDriver.startAndroidSession (/Users/prabhakary/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/lib/sessions/android.ts:38:5)
    at FlutterDriver.createSession (/Users/prabhakary/node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/lib/sessions/session.ts:45:43)
    at AppiumDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:731:35)
[c070e00a][HTTP] <-- POST /session 500 9242 ms - 736 

Below are my execution steps:

Executing appium via terminal: appium server --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload

Appium server running on  http://127.0.0.1:4723/


AVD: Pixel API 31 with 12.0 version is up and running
VS code -> Project -> Terminal

Run npx wdio run config/android/wdio.android.conf.ts




We tried checking all wdio.config.ts
Ensure debug.apk is used

wdio.android.config.ts

import type {Options} from '@wdio/types'

export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
    runner: 'local',
   // path:  '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    autoCompileOpts: {
        autoCompile: true,
        tsNodeOpts: {
            project: './tsconfig.json',
            transpileOnly: true,
        },
    },

    specs: ['../../tests/**/*.ts'],
    exclude: [],

    maxInstances: 1,

    capabilities: [
        {
            platformName: 'Android',
            'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel API 31',
            'appium:platformVersion': '12.0',
            'appium:automationName': 'Flutter',
            'appium:appPackage': 'com.ziing.app',
            //'appium:app': 'build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
            'appium:app': '/Users/prabhakary/Downloads/Prabhakar_debug_build/app-debug.apk',
            'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true,
           
            
            //'appium:chromedriverExecutable': 'chromedriver/chromedriver.exe',
        },
    ],

    logLevel: 'info',


    bail: 0,

    waitforTimeout: 10000,

    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,

    connectionRetryCount: 3,

   //services: ['appium'],

    framework: 'mocha',

    reporters: ['spec'],

    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000,
    },

}



please help on this isssue

Solved working fine ,instead of running using  npx wdio run config/android/wdio.android.conf.ts Execute a single spec file using --spec flag.
